# How long to wait to upgrade ASP.NET or .NET Framework for my project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a project that runs on ASP.net 2 something and .NET framework 2 something. How long do people typically wait to upgrade their apps to the latest ASP.NET and .NET framework version?

Comment: With "people", do you mean us developers or do you mean consumers?

Comment: "it depends". If you're not going to change the application, then you don't need the new features, and you don't have to hurry. OTOH, if you have other applications using later versions, then you'd just as well get them all to the latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some "people" as soon as possible - preferably while the newest version is still in beta :)

some "people" after the first servicepack

Some "people" never

Some "people" only if the client is paying for it

But in general I would say after the initial bugs are out and there is a mild case to upgrade due to new features (e.g. easier URL rewriting, client side ID's, threading, Linq, EF etc) or improved security or other aspects like higher developer productivity.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not developing the site/application, just leave it running as is until additional work is done, then upgrade it if its fairly straight forward or required.

At a minimum we tend to upgrade our Visual Studio Versions as they are released then upgrade applications shortly after that.

Answer (score 1):

With web apps the platform you develop against is largely irrelevant to your users.  So the answer is “Sometime after your hosting server has been updated to handle the new platform” and “As soon as you have a need to use/feel comfortable with the new tools and have the time to go through testing to make sure nothing broke”.

In my case we have had the licenses to work in VS 2010 and .net 4 for about a year, and a few projects have come along that would have been easier with some of the new features, but our server groups have been stalling on the infrastructure upgrades so we are still locked at no higher than .net 3.5.  I typically pick up the new version of the tools with a new project but I don’t try to bring old code up-to-date until after I am comfortable with the differences and a fairly major revision is needed.  The whole if it is not broke don’t fix it concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you're web app is working perfectly and performing well, why upgrade at all?

You should only upgrade if this upgrade fixes something, or adds a feature that you need. Upgrading for upgrading's sake is of no use to anybody, and can be quite dangerous sometimes as there's always the possibility of breaking something in the process.